# Cubic character armature deform

Tags: mesh, rigging, blender-internal-render-engine, armature, rigify

I am making characters similar to minecraft . This is the product that i make myself.
[image]

However... look at that arm. I am having trouble trying to find out what's the problem with it . This is the final product that i wish to have.
[image]

I want my character arm to be excatly like the second picture .
Anyone can help?

Comment: There are too many vertices in your arm. If you leave only 1 loop in the elbow with 50% weighting on both bones you'll get the correct result with armature modifier set to Preserve Volume. If you need more vertex resolution you will have to make corrective shapekeys or corrective bones to get this shape.

Comment: Sorry , i tried doing what you said but am still in a state of confusion.And one more thing . How can i add the rig movement limit. I have added the file that i wish my final product will be like . ( look up there ) If you try to move the arm ik up . It stop when the arm is at its limit . how do i do that? And please continue helping me in the deform part .