# Can I make video game clips from any game like Minecraft ones?

Tags: video

I'm new to Blender, but I've noticed people have Minecraft templates where you can change skins. Can you do this with any video game clip?

Can I record a clip from Call of Duty then take 10 seconds of it, or a pic (not sure which), then put it in Blender and make my own skins and whatever in it, just like the Minecraft ones?

Or do I have to actually make my own and not be able to take the models in my clip?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Blender Stackexchange. It would be helpful if you would change your headline into something more meaningful. Also try to add as many useful information in your question as possible, like links to videos or images, if necessary.

Comment: As zeffii mentioned bellow, no you cannot do that easily. If you record a video of gameplay you can't just easily change stuff and game assets from the video alone. There are many Minecraft templates because of its blocky nature and simplified graphics make it easy to recreate the content, and there are plentiful actual 3D models of the game assets to render in Blender

Answer (score 3, accepted):

People can make Minecraft videos in Blender by importing characters+rigging and worlds and then animate and render them. For example this question has images that shows some of the process:

[Cubic character armature deform](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41573/cubic-character-armature-deform)

It's not like people are making screen captures of a game they played, then importing that video and applying a different skin/texture to the characters, that's not how it works. It would be the same as if you recorded a bit of Starwars and expected there to be an easy way to redress all the storm troopers to look like indiana jones.

---

Currently there are no easy ways to replace garments on recorded footage, but that doesn't mean there aren't complicated ways.

#### The literature

Ways are emerging to help automate the process of [match making and garment replacement](http://graphics.tu-bs.de/publications/rogge2014garmentreplacement_tog/), but they are early proof of concept, and are not likely to be included in Blender any time soon (or indeed possibly never)

Comment: Thank you very much that really helped :) Im a sony vegas expert so I thought I would now get into blender type stuff

Answer (score 0):

Minecraft is created with a design philosophy promoting user created content. If Call of Duty has the same design principles and an exporter from Blender and an importer to COD, then you might be able to do what you want. I don't play COD, an can not answer whether it's possible to do what you want in that game or not.